# How to import cocoapod into Xcode 7.3?

Tags: xcode, uitableview, cocoapods, swift-playground

I've looked through many guides and they all seem to point to using the 'link_with' command for the podfile, like this tutorial:

https://littlebitesofcocoa.com/138-using-cocoapods-in-xcode-playgrounds

However when I try this, cocoapod doesn't seem to like the syntax of my podfile and will tell me that 'link_with' is now unsupported and it seems to interpret the name of the playground file as a podfile.

```
target 'Jawn’ do
  link_with 'UrlMetaData'             <----- (UrlMetaData.playground)
  use_frameworks!
  platform :ios, '8.4'
  pod 'Kanna', '~> 1.0.0'
  pod 'SlackTextViewController'
  pod 'M13ProgressSuite'
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.4'
  pod 'YouTubePlayer'
  workspace 'Jawn'
end
```

when I do pod install I'll get the following output:

```
My-iMac:MyProject USERNAME$ pod install

[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: [!] The specification of `link_with` in the Podfile is now unsupported, please use target blocks instead..

 #  from /Users/USERNAME/Xcode Projects/MyProject/Podfile:2
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #  target 'Jawn' do
 >    link_with 'UrlMetaData'
 #    use_frameworks!
 #  -------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have multiple target,

write your podfile like this.

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, ‘8.0’
use_frameworks!

def pods

pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.4'
pod 'EZSwiftExtensions'

end

target 'AppName' do
    pods
end

target 'AppNameTests' do
   pods 
end
```

if you have multiple targets it will be helpful to add all your dependencies in one place.

Answer (score 0):

Place your podfile in the folder where your project is and make sure your target is right.

My pod file looks like this:

```
target 'ProjectName' do

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, ‘8.0’
use_frameworks!

pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.4'

end
```

Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

## Install pods with Xcode 7.3

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'demoAlamofire' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  
  # Pods for demoAlamofire

  pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire'
  pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git'

  target 'demoAlamofireTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'demoAlamofireUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```